# Using groups in regex for json parsing for the given data in a single line

Tags: python, regex

I understand there is a method in python for json parsing, however I am trying to learn to do this by developing specific regex for a given question.

For example:-
this is the given json file:-

```
{
    "mac" : "58:1C:0A:6E:39:4D",
    "programName" : "Return of Jedi",
    "speed" : 35.23,
    "isActive" : false,
    "options": [ "fixed", "complete" , "inTransit" , "active" ],
    "balance" : -9999,
    "brand" : "stuxnet",
    "communityThread" : "11.22",
    "passcode": "true",
    "points" : [ "A", "B", "C", "3D", "-1Z"]
}
```

this is what i have developed so far:-

```
for group 1(strings:strings) = (\"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?\"(.+?)\") 
for group 2 (strings: numbers) = \"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|-?[0-9]+)
for group 3 (strings:T/F) = (\"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?(true|false))
```

I will use re.search, where I want to put the an entire pattern for the above json parsing along with its groups in a single line. 
please help with the "options" and "points" group ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like this:-

```
answerDictionary = {}
with open(inputfile, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if "[" not in line:
            searchResult = re.search('\"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?\"(.+?)\"|\"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?(true|false)|\"([\w]+?)\"[\s]?:[\s]?(-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+|-?[0-9]+)', line)
            if searchResult is not None:
                if(searchResult.group(1) is not None):
                    answerDictionary[searchResult.group(1)] = searchResult.group(2)
                elif (searchResult.group(3) is not None):
                    answerDictionary[searchResult.group(3)] = searchResult.group(4)
                elif (searchResult.group(5) is not None):
                    answerDictionary[searchResult.group(5)] = .group(6)
            else:
              searchResult = re.findall("\"(.+?)\"", line)
              answerDictionary[searchResult[0]] = x[1:]
```

This will return a dictionary with all the groups that you described above.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot this, helps alot.